# jquery get next div called moreProductsBox and slideToggle it open

Tags: jquery, this, slidetoggle

Trying to get access to the next available div after the a link that i click, with a class of moreProductsBox and then slideToggle it open.

This is what i have now:

Link:

```
<div class="productContent">
<p><a href="#" onclick="return false;"  class="viewMoreProducts">View Related Products </a></p>
</div>
<div class="productSelectBar">
<div class="selectBar">
</div>
</div>

<!-- View More Products Box -->
<div class="moreProductsBox" style="display:none;">
</div>
```

Jquery is:

```
// Show Hidden Product Boxes on Expand  
$(".viewMoreProducts").click(function() {
    $(this).nextAll(".moreProductsBox:first").slideToggle()
};
```

*Updated markup to be more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only way for me to access that next div with the class moreProductsBox was to do:

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".moreProductsBox:first").slideToggle();
```

The other suggestions that were given didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

How is `.moreProductsBox` related to `.viewMoreProducts` in the document? Is it a sibling, or a child of some other element further down your document? If it is a sibling, but not the *very next* one, you might try:

```
$(this).nextAll(".moreProductsBox:first").slideToggle();
```

since `.next` will only get you the *very next sibling*.

Comment: the p link viewMoreProducts is a few divs up away (still a sibling i guess) from the hidden div called moreProductsBox. There are going to be many sections with hidden divs for each.

Comment: @estern - you really should show your markup, otherwise we will just be guessing at how to select the right element.

Comment: i know the markup i am just not sure if it is sibling. The order of items goes like this: <p><a></a></p> then a few divs before the div that i am trying to access which has a class of moreProductsBox

Comment: I updated the question markup to help clarify the code and jquery code that i currently am using

Answer (score 0):

next works on sibling nodes, there is no 'next' div in your html

http://api.jquery.com/next/

*Description: Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.*

post the html which contains both your anchor and div mark up, you probably want something like

```
// this should work if the p tag has a sibling div moreProductsBox
$(this).parent().next('moreProductsBox').slideToggle;
```